# Automatically redirects to another route after ajax post update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I've made crud using ajax but when i update in Ajax, instead of staying on the same page it automatically redirects to another route.

```
Route::get('/news', 'NewsController@index')->name('news'); 
Route::post('/news/save/', 'NewsController@saveUpdate')->name('news.saveUpdate');

function ajaxSaveUpdate(){
   $.ajax({
        url: "{{route('news.saveUpdate')}}",
        type: "post",
        data: {
           _token:"{{csrf_token()}}",
           "id":$('#hid-id').val(),
           "title":$('#edit_title').val(),
           "description":$("#edit_description").val(),
           "status":$("#edit_status").val()
        },
        success: function(response){
            table.clear();
            ajaxLoad();
        }
   });
}
```

here, after i change the data in the form and submit it for update. I get :

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251:
```

it will keep showing the same error if i refresh it with f5 key / ctrl+r . But if i click on the address bar(field in the browser where you type url) and press "enter" key it leads me to main page/ where it is supposed to go instead of showing "HttpException" again like when i pressed "f5" refresh key.

To get rid of this error i'll have to change the route :

```
Route::get('/news', 'NewsController@index')->name('news');
```

to

```
Route::post('/news', 'NewsController@index')->name('news');
```

But, It's not supposed to go to '/news' route, instead it should enter :

```
 Route::post('/news/save', 'NewsController@saveUpdate')->name('news.saveUpdate');
```

Question : Why does it automatically go to the first route instead of the second   without being redirected? How do i solve the error?

P.s. I haven't redirected the page to the first route in controller or any other files. Any suggestions to improve the way i code will be appreciated . Thanks!!

Comment: can you view source and check the value of url if it's actually pointing to /news/save/? also, what does ajaxLoad() function do?

Comment: function ajaxSaveUpdate(){
       $.ajax({
            url: "{{route('news.saveUpdate')}}", the url points the route /news/save. ajaxLoad function loads all the data from the database and prints on the table.

Comment: i mean what's the actual value of url, when you do 'View page source' in the browser? try also to clear your browser cache.

Comment: no, instead of '/news/save/' it's pointing to '/news' . Already tried clearing the browser cache.

Comment: i'm not really sure about laravel naming rules for routes, but can you try changing 'news.saveUpdate' to just 'saveUpdate'? both on your route definition and ajax url?

Comment: Did you add the `event.preventDefault()` in your click or submit handler to prevent the default action

Comment: yup i did! @chanafdo

Comment: I wonder if it's because of the dot in your route name.  Try it without, see if you get the correct url generated when you view source.

Comment: nah, already tried it. :<

Comment: I tried it on my laravel setup, and route('news.saveUpdate') returns /news/save.  Do you have a route anything like POST /news/{somenewsId} which occurs before /news/save?